# Add a caption for the user while the item is being deleted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button on my site with which the user can remove any position from the table.

Procedure: the user clicks on the delete button (in my case it is DeleteForeverIcon) -> a window appears in which the user can cancel the action or confirm -> after confirming the action, the process of deleting the entry begins and the dialog box disappears when the deletion of the entry is completed

Everything is simple here and everything works.
Code below.
Problem description after code

```
export function DeleteButton({ item }) {
  const { urlParams } = useContext(PageContext)
  const { firestore } = useContext(AppContext)
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

return <ButtonGroup>
          <DeleteForeverIcon onClick={handleClickOpen} />
         
          <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
              
              <DialogActions>
                <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
                <Button color="error" onClick={() => { deleteItem(item, firestore, urlParams) }}>
                  Confirm
                </Button>
              </DialogActions>

          </Dialog>

  </ButtonGroup >
}
```

The problem is that if the record is too large in size, then the deletion process takes a long time, not instantly (from 2 seconds or more). And all this time, while the deletion process is in progress, the dialog box is open without any signs of an ongoing action. And the user may get the impression that the site is frozen or the delete button is not working.
I would like that after clicking on the "Сonfirm" button, during the deletion process there would be an inscription notifying about this - The deletion process is in progress (or something similar. Here I will come up with it myself, the main thing for me is to understand the essence of how to do it)

```
export function deleteItem(item, firestore) {
    if (item instanceof Record) { deleteRecord(firestore, item.id)}
   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do about it is to display a `loading` state on your button after the action has been triggered. Something like:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const onSomeActionTriggered = async () => {
  try {
    setLoading(true);
    await someLongDurationAction();
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
};

return <button>{loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Confirm'}</button>
```

Here's a [Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-shockley-4zwyby?file=/src/App.js) of what I mean.

You could also trigger a loading state after the alert has been closed, if you think that would be better for your UX.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention to my question. There is one nuance: as I understand it, you set the default time value (5000 milliseconds), and during this time it works out "Loading ...". But the problem is that I do not know how long the deletion takes (it is always different and depends on the file size)

Comment: @Paul that is used just to simulate your deletion action. It doesn't matter if the actions takes 5000 ms or 10000ms or 300ms, it will trigger the loading state and, on completion, the loading state will end.

Comment: Unfortunately, or I'm using your code incorrectly in my code. But my loading depends on the time that I specify, and not on the actual time of deletion.

Perhaps you can help me to properly integrate your code with mine.

Comment: Is your delete action awaitable? Is it returning a `Promise`? Would it be possible to show me the code of your `deleteItem` function? Or at least give a simulation of it?

Comment: I added deleteItem function

Comment: @Paul ok, I have updated the [Codesandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-shockley-4zwyby?file=/src/App.js). I hope this is what you're looking for

Comment: I once again approached the study of your answer, and this time I understood everything. And I got the desired result. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

because deleting an item is an async operation you must wait for result and your `firestore.collection("records").doc(recordId).delete()` should return a promise. so if `firestore` returns a promise, Follow the steps below(and Probably so because you used await before it):
**first** await in your `Dialog component` and display a loading:
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

```
const handleClickDeleteItem= () => {
  setLoading(true);
  await deleteItem()
  setLoading(false);
};
```

**now** your `deleteItem()` function will be:

```
export function deleteItem(item, firestore, urlParams) {
    if (item instanceof Record) { await deleteRecord(firestore, item.id)}
}
```

**and** your `deleteRecord` function  is smae as before.

**if** `firestore.collection("records").doc(recordId).delete()` doesn't return a promise you should create a promise in its `delete()` function and after completing delete operation resolve it like below:

first do above steps.
in your `delete()` function create a promise object and put your operation in it and then return promise object. so your `delet()` funcion will be:

```
  {
    const myResolve = () => {};

    let myPromise = new Promise(function (myResolve, reject) {
      //do your operations here....
      myResolve();
    });

    return myPromise;
  }
```

note: when you use async operation in a function(`delete()` in this example), every other function that use result of this function must have an await word before itself(like `deleteRecord()` and `deleteItem()` in this example).